# Can't drop Index Constraint

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to first drop the index and then the PK (because ultimately I'm gonna need to do a truncate on this table).

Here's a screen shot of this table and constraints:

[image]

Here are the 2 constraints (code obtained from clipboard after I right-click them and do a create to clipboard in SQL 2008):

(the Primary Key)

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Entry] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Entry_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

(supposedly this is the create index code, after I do a right-click create to clipboard..but it's the same exact code! not sure why):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Entry] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Entry_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping the primary key should drop the index as well as the index was automatically created when you created the primary key.

You only need to drop the Foreign Key constraints when you need to truncate a table. This is to make sure there are no tables dependent on it.

Comment: ok well I can't drop the PK, because then I get the error saying it's tied to an index....so it seems like a chicken and egg situation.

Comment: did, but what I'm ultimately wanting to do is I have that table and I neeed to reimport all records but I don't want to reseed the PK identity meaning I'm porting over Identies that skip numbers.  So for example one of the first records in the data I'm reinserting into this table has a PK of 45...not 1.  So trying to clear what's there in the table, and take off constraints, then import, then put back on constraints.  So ultimately I WILL need to take off the PK constraint temporarily until I import and then put that PK and other  constraints back in.

Comment: Truncating the table should reset the identity. If you don't want that you'd do a DELETE. You could trying setting the seed of the identity to 45 instead of default 1 after truncating

Comment: what I need is the identity to be GONE for a second so I can insert and then put back on the identity so that any new records are incremented going forward.

Comment: By default, insert is not allowed into an identity column. But you turn it off for a specific table by execute `SET IDENTITY_XXXXX` off. I can't remember the command right now. You could find it through google

Comment: crap did not know of that, I did google but did not see this yet.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, and can't, drop the index associated with the primary key.  All you need to do is drop the primary key and the index will be removed.

If you're going to truncate the data, you shouldn't have to drop the primary key though.

If you can't truncate the table, then you should remove foreign keys that reference this table.  I assume that you removed foreign keys where this table references other tables, because we don't see any in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Constant and index are not the same.
But in some syntax an index is referred to as a constraint.
You have 5 constraints and one index.
You did not like notice it has the same name in both spots **PK_Entry_ID**.
A PK is an index.

And an index does not prevent a truncate.

A FK prevents a truncate.

If you are tying to drop the index the why are you creating a script to create.
Create a script to drop and drop it.